# How do take input from user in optparse?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following file:

```
System Configuration Utility Version 14.1 Build 19
Copyright (c) 2017 Intel Corporation

System BIOS and FW Versions:
BIOS Version............. SE3.4

ME Firmware Version...... 2.01

BMC Version
 Op Code................. 1.2.7Q

SDR Version.............. SDR Package 0.1
```

I want to capture it and store in a dict as:

```
d ={'BMC Version': '1.2.7Q',
    'SDR Version': '0.1',
    'ME Firmware Version': '2.01'
   }
```

How do I do it using regex and python?

Right now my approach is to hardcode it like this but I don't want to hardcode:

```
SDR Package \d+.\d+
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to hardcode? What kind of solution do you want? And how is the question relate to optparse?

Comment: What in the world does optparse have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: [`((?:ME Firmware|BMC|SDR) Version)\D+([0-9.A-Za-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/OiYyE2/2)

Details:

- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `|` Or
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

**Python code**:

```
import re

d = {}
for match in re.findall(r'((?:ME Firmware|BMC|SDR) Version)\D+([0-9.A-Z]+)', text):
    d[match[0]] = match[1]
```

Output:

```
{'ME Firmware Version': '2.01', 'BMC Version': '1.2.7Q', 'SDR Version': '0.1'}
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/RqVbFv)